# How can I get my if statement to work properly when a csv value does not exist?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, error-handling

The issue I am currently having is that my IF statement for my CVSParser is not working. The countryname "Germany" doesn't exist which is ok but the string notf is not returning when this error occurs instead I get:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for Germany not found, expected one of [Country, Exports, Value (dollars)]".

I assumed the value that was being returned was a null value because CVSParser returns a String, however, assigning a null value to countryName is not getting my code to work.

The issue came up when I was using tester.

What steps do I need to take to fix? Also in general how I do figure out the value a method is returning when what it's looking for doesn't exist? (Specifically when it's not in the documentation.)

```
public String countryInfo (CSVParser parser,String country){
    FileResource fr = new FileResource();
    String exports= "";
    String countryName= "";
    String value= "";
    for (CSVRecord record : parser){
        exports=record.get("Exports");
        countryName=record.get(country);
        value= record.get("Value");
        if (exports== null ||countryName!= country){
            String notf= "info has not been found";
            return notf;
        }
    }
    String info= countryName +":"+ exports;
    return info;
}

public void tester (){
    FileResource fr = new FileResource();
    CSVParser parser = fr.getCSVParser();
    countryInfo(parser,"Germany");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure in countryName=record.get(country), the argument country shouldn't be "Country"  (not "Germany") ?

Comment: @paisanco I'll edit my code to show the test I did that was giving me the error I got.

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HovercraftFullOfEels remarks about string comparison are right.

But the exception says

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for Germany not found,
>   expected one of [Country, Exports, Value (dollars)]"

and the test code results in a call

```
countryName=record.get("Germany");
```

where the exception suggests it should have been

```
countryName=record.get("Country");
```

So if you want information about Germany's exports, the code should be

```
public String countryInfo (CSVParser parser,String desiredCountry){
     FileResource fr = new FileResource();
     String exports= "";
    String countryName= "";
     String value= "";
    for (CSVRecord record : parser){
      exports=record.get("Exports");
      countryName=record.get("Country");
      value= record.get("Value");
      if (exports== null || !countryName.equals(desiredCountry)){
        String notf= "info has not been found";
        return notf;
      }
    }
    String info= countryName +":"+ exports;
    return info;
       }
public void tester (){
        FileResource fr = new FileResource();
        CSVParser parser = fr.getCSVParser();
        countryInfo(parser,"Germany");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I just needed to change my code around a bit to work. Instead of checking what the value of CountryName is I check if it even exists in CVSParser. If it doesn't exist I assign x with the string value of "information not found". If the information is their then x is assigned the export, values, etc. I had to rethink my problem and not make it more complicated than it has to be.

```
public String countryInfo (CSVParser parser,String country){
         String exports= "";
         String countryName= "";
         String value= "";
         String x= null;

         for (CSVRecord record:parser){
             String countries= record.get("Country");
             if (countries.contains(country)){
                  countryName=record.get(country);
                  value=record.get("Value");
                  exports= record.get("Exports");
                  x= countryName+":"+exports+":"+value;    
               }
              else{
                x= "information not found";
               }       
           }    
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you hit on the solution while I was writing my answer !

Comment: @paisanco lol yeah. I have been struggling with knowing when something is false, a -1, etc. I'm still struggling in that realm